# Vertical and Horizontal Grouping in Kendo Scheduler

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-scheduler

Can I use Kendo UI scheduler to create the following view-

[image]

What I found on Kendo site, we can create the vertical grouping with Floor and Room, but can we create it with horizontal month grouping/month view?

Also I found some classes to create custom views like kendo.ui.AgendaView and kendo.ui.MultiDayView ([here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/scheduling/scheduler/how-to/custom-view)) but these and similar functionality classes (which we can extend to create another custom views) are not documented anywhere.